# Checking if values in vector is included in range of values in different dataset

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I'm working in R and have a large dataframe (my database= "db") that contains different m/z masses which correspond to a peptide sequence like such:

```
    peptide MZ
    WV  304.16558
    VR  274.18738
    VR  274.18738
    LP  229.15468
    IP  229.15468
    IP  229.15468
    FP  263.13903
```

And a second dataframe ("df") that has a range of MZ peptides like such:

```
mzmin        mzmax
296.2286    296.2584
296.8832    297.0105
299.1425    299.1511
301.1299    301.2393
301.0612    301.1668
302.106     302.1985
```

What I want to do is check if rows in the first data frame fits within the range of the second data frame and if so add the Peptide sequence (column 1 of the first data frame) to the second data frame.
Are there any R functions that could help me with accomplishing this task?

i've used:

```
# order the first data.frame by the ranges

df <- df[order(df[[1]]), ]

# create a vector breaks from the interval ranges

breaks <- as.vector(do.call(rbind, df[c(1,2)]))
ints <- ceiling(findInterval(db[[2]], breaks)/2)

df$ <- df[ints, 3]
```

Comment: It would help if your data had some matches :-)

Comment: Once you update the question with sample data that provides a match, please show what your expected output (given that sample data) should look like. My guess is that `fuzzyjoin::fuzzy_left_join` (among two other alternatives) will do what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to have a match, so I added a line to df for between 229 to 230. This solution uses `dplyr`

```
df %>% rowwise() %>% 
   mutate(pptz=ifelse(is.null(db$peptide[between(db$MZ,mzmin,mzmax)]), NA, 
      paste(unique(db$peptide[between(db$MZ,mzmin,mzmax)]),collapse=", ")))
Source: local data frame [7 x 3]
Groups: <by row>

# A tibble: 7 x 3
  mzmin mzmax pptz    
  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>   
1  296.  296. ""      
2  297.  297. ""      
3  299.  299. ""      
4  301.  301. ""      
5  301.  301. ""      
6  302.  302. ""      
7  229   230  "LP, IP"
```

Answer (score 3):

I think the concept of "non-equi" or "range" join is appropriate here. This can be done in R with three methods: `fuzzyjoin`, `data.table`, or some form of SQL (e.g., `sqldf`).

Similar to @iod, I'm injecting some fake data in order to find a match. Namely, I added a range of `228-230` into `df`.

```r
out <- fuzzyjoin::fuzzy_left_join(
  df, db,
  by = c("mzmin" = "MZ", "mzmax" = "MZ"),
  match_fun = list(`<=`, `>=`)
)
out
#      mzmin    mzmax peptide       MZ
# 1 228.0000 230.0000      LP 229.1547
# 2 228.0000 230.0000      IP 229.1547
# 3 228.0000 230.0000      IP 229.1547
# 4 296.2286 296.2584    <NA>       NA
# 5 296.8832 297.0105    <NA>       NA
# 6 299.1425 299.1511    <NA>       NA
# 7 301.1299 301.2393    <NA>       NA
# 8 301.0612 301.1668    <NA>       NA
# 9 302.1060 302.1985    <NA>       NA
```

This shows that two peptides (LP and IP) match the new range. One question I have is what to do with multiple matches like this, and the best case depends on how you are using it.

1. If you just want to print it out and you'll never deal with the peptides as data again, then we can combine/concatenate them into one string, e.g., `"LP, IP"` or `"LP, IP, IP"`.
2. If you want to compact the frame but will be using them as data later, then I discourage string-concatenation, as it means you have to re-parse it out later. This is relatively simple, but prone to problems if there are any non-standard peptide strings out there. In this case, I recommend list-columns for storing the data.
3. If you don't need to compact the frame, then keep it in the longer-format, accepting the repeat `mzmin`/`mzmax` pairs.

The three options, demonstrated:

1. string-concatenation:

   ```r
   do.call(rbind, by(out, out[,c("mzmin", "mzmax")], FUN = function(z) {
     within(z, {
       peptide = if (any(!is.na(peptide))) paste(na.omit(peptide), collapse = ",") else NA_character_
     })[1,]
   }))
   #      mzmin    mzmax  peptide
   # 1 228.0000 230.0000 LP,IP,IP
   # 4 296.2286 296.2584     <NA>
   # 5 296.8832 297.0105     <NA>
   # 6 299.1425 299.1511     <NA>
   # 8 301.0612 301.1668     <NA>
   # 7 301.1299 301.2393     <NA>
   # 9 302.1060 302.1985     <NA>
   ```
2. list-columns

   ```r
   do.call(rbind, by(out, out[,c("mzmin", "mzmax")], FUN = function(z) {
     within(z, {
       peptide = if (any(!is.na(peptide))) list(na.omit(peptide)) else list(NA_character_)
     })[1,]
   }))
   #      mzmin    mzmax    peptide
   # 1 228.0000 230.0000 LP, IP, IP
   # 4 296.2286 296.2584         NA
   # 5 296.8832 297.0105         NA
   # 6 299.1425 299.1511         NA
   # 8 301.0612 301.1668         NA
   # 7 301.1299 301.2393         NA
   # 9 302.1060 302.1985         NA
   ```

   While this looks similar, it is not ... each "element" within the `peptide` column is actually its own vector. Unfortunately, anything that typically deals with a frame's column and expects a vector will not work with this, since ... it's a `list`, not a `vector`. It works well but takes a little adjustment.
3. Keep it. Well, no demonstration required. (Though you can always use `!duplicated(.)` to reduce the dupes in it.)

Other methods of range-join:

- SQL in general supports it. The use of `sqldf` prevents the need to import data to a DBMS, process it, and query it back.

  ```r
  sqldf::sqldf("
    select df.mzmin, df.mzmax, db.peptide
    from df
      left join db on df.mzmin <= db.MZ and df.mzmax >= db.MZ")
  #      mzmin    mzmax peptide
  # 1 228.0000 230.0000      LP
  # 2 228.0000 230.0000      IP
  # 3 228.0000 230.0000      IP
  # 4 296.2286 296.2584    <NA>
  # 5 296.8832 297.0105    <NA>
  # 6 299.1425 299.1511    <NA>
  # 7 301.1299 301.2393    <NA>
  # 8 301.0612 301.1668    <NA>
  # 9 302.1060 302.1985    <NA>
  ```

  or more succinctly with `between`:

  ```r
  sqldf::sqldf("
    select df.mzmin, df.mzmax, db.peptide
    from df
      left join db on db.MZ between df.mzmin and df.mzmax")
  ```
- `data.table` package

  ```r
  library(data.table)
  dbDT <- as.data.table(db)
  dfDT <- as.data.table(df)
  dbDT[dfDT, on = .(MZ >= mzmin, MZ <= mzmax)]
  #    peptide       MZ     MZ.1
  # 1:      LP 228.0000 230.0000
  # 2:      IP 228.0000 230.0000
  # 3:      IP 228.0000 230.0000
  # 4:    <NA> 296.2286 296.2584
  # 5:    <NA> 296.8832 297.0105
  # 6:    <NA> 299.1425 299.1511
  # 7:    <NA> 301.1299 301.2393
  # 8:    <NA> 301.0612 301.1668
  # 9:    <NA> 302.1060 302.1985
  ```

  Note: if you aren't already using `data.table`, then make sure you convert to `data.table` formats before attempting this. It works because the package knows what to do with its own objects.

---

Data:

```r
db <- structure(list(peptide = c("WV", "VR", "VR", "LP", "IP", "IP", "FP"), MZ = c(304.16558, 274.18738, 274.18738, 229.15468, 229.15468, 229.15468, 263.13903)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
df <- structure(list(mzmin = c(228, 296.2286, 296.8832, 299.1425, 301.1299, 301.0612, 302.106), mzmax = c(230, 296.2584, 297.0105, 299.1511, 301.2393, 301.1668, 302.1985)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```